# Upgrading .net client to TSL1.2 to communicate to restful service

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, security, ssl

I am trying to hit a restful service from asp.net client. I am making a web request and setting proxy and other parameters. The web server will accept only the secure set of cipher suites basically latest patched version of OpenSSL.

This is below code:

```
            //string acadiaPath = "https://Test/AP/get?v=1&sk=0";
            //string User = "****";
            //string Pword = "******";

            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

            System.Net.WebRequest request = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(acadiaPath);

            request.Method = "GET";

            request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

            request.ContentLength = 0;

            Uri newUri = new Uri(proxyAddress);

            myProxy.Address = newUri;

            myProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

            request.Proxy = myProxy;

            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(acadiaUser, acadiaPword);

            System.Net.HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as System.Net.HttpWebResponse;

            Stream objResponseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(objResponseStream);

            string objResponseString = reader.ReadToEnd();

            MessageBox.Show(objResponseStream.ToString());
```

but this not getting through and below error comes:

"The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send."

The reason is :

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

This is not providing TSL1.2 as my client code is on 4.0.

How can I use TSL1.2 without upgrading to 4.5 from my c# code. I mean by using 4.5 provided system.net DLL or any other things

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot switch to 4.5?

Comment: yes. The current setup is on XP and we do not want to go for additional cost. Any workaround to use it on 4.0 ?